Can the 'view_item' Event in GA4 Generate Revenue?
I have a view_item event on my page, and I am wondering if this event will generate a revenue amount. Based on the structure of the data layer, it includes currency and a value, but inside the GA4 report, it doesn't show the revenue. I double-checked all values inside the data layer object and verified that they are correct in terms of both values and formatting. Additionally, I checked this event using Tag Assistant, and it is triggering.
// VIEW ITEM DATALAYER
            dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });
            dataLayer.push({
                event: "view_item",
                ecommerce: {
                    currency: "PHP",
                    value: parseFloat(amount),
                    items: [
                        {
                            item_id: drupalSettings.app.base_url,
                            item_name: drupalSettings.app.campaign_name,
                            item_category: paymentScheme, // One time or monthly
                            price: parseFloat(amount),
                            quantity: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });



From what I read, it looks like the only event capable of generating revenue is the purchase event, since it contains the transaction_id needed to track revenue, while the view_item event doesn't have this property.
I have updated my purchase event to include item_category2 for tracking the payment method.
Reference: GA4/GTM - How to track revenue for a custom event in GA4?
